# Watir element containing embedded parentheses reporting as not visible?, not present? and not exists?

Tags: watir-webdriver

Watir is reporting that actually visible text, isn't visible if the string I'm searching for contains parentheses unless the search string starts and ends with parentheses.

I am testing a non-public web page that contains (and displays) a string that looks like this

```
Maintenance Configuration (2) database
```

A search for "Maintenance Configuration (2) database" using include? returns true.  (A search for a string not on the page, returns false.)

However, a search for "Maintenance Configuration (2) database" using exists? or present? returns false and a visible? will cause a crash.

But, a search for "Maintenance Configuration", "(2)" or "database" using exists?, present? or visible? will return true.

One of my failing tests (false) is

```
text = "Maintenance Configuration (2) database" 
puts "present?: " + @browser.div(:text => text).present?.to_s
```

And one of my passing tests (true) is

```
text = "Maintenance Configuration" 
puts "present?: " + @browser.div(:text => text).present?.to_s
```

I also tried this (which also returned false).

```
text = "Maintenance Configuration \(2\) database" 
puts "present?: " + @browser.div(:text => text).present?.to_s
```

Plus I tried these out of desperation

```
text = "Maintenance\sConfiguration\s(2)\sdatabase"    # => false
text = "Maintenance\sConfiguration\s\(2\)\sdatabase"  # => false
text = "(2)"   # => true
text = " (2)"  # => false
text = "(2) "  # => false
```

The variable here appears to be if the string contains parentheses or not -- with the exception that if the () are in the first and last position, I get true.

I'm puzzled.  Any ideas?

Edit #1 - Response to request for HTML markup.
I'm not allowed to give you the HTML markup that I'm testing but I can do better.  I can give you simple HTML code that reproduces the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    Hello world<br />
    foo bar(2) bletch<br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I can see "Hello world", "foo bar", "(2)" and "bletch" with .visible?  Attempting to find "foo bar(2) bletch" with .visible? causes a crash.

Is that enough or do you need something more?

Edit #2.  (Hopefully no typos as I am not able to copy/paste)

```
def tester(myString)
    puts ( "Testing: #{myString}" )
    puts ( @browser.div(:text => /#{myString.gsub(/\s/, '\s')}/).present? )
end

when /^I test Watir$/ do
    @browser.goto("file:///vagrant/test/stack.html")

    Watir::Wait.until(5) { @browser.text.include? "Hello" }

    tester ( "Hello world" )
    tester ( "foo bar" )
    tester ( "(2)" )
    tester ( " bletch" )
    tester ( "foo bar(2) bletch" )
end
```

The first 4 print true and the last one prints false.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide the HTML as the markup can make a huge difference.

Comment: I edited my original post so that it includes HTML markup that will produce the problem (for me).

Comment: Can you also provide the Watir code that you used with the simplified example page? It sounds like you are saying that `browser.div(:text => "Hello world").visible?` will return true. It raises an exception when I try, which is what I would expect. An exception being raised for `browser.div(:text => "foo bar(2) bletch").visible?` would be expected since the div's text does not exactly match. In terms of exact text matching, only `browser.div(:text => "Hello world foo bar(2) bletch").visible?` would return true.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Yes, I erred; sorry.  I needed gsub.  I updated my post with Edit #2; which contains code I wrote this morning to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parenthesis are causing an issue because they eventually get used in a regular expression (regexp). Parenthesis have a special meaning and need to be escaped to be used as a literal character.

You can see in the following line that a Regexp is used for the text locator (the Regexp is denoted by the "/"):

```
@browser.div(:text => /#{myString.gsub(/\s/, '\s')}/).present?
```

When the text "foo bar(2) bletch" is passed to the method, due to the Regexp, Watir is actually looking for a div with text that contains "foo bar2 bletch". The parenthesis are not included in the search since they only provide a grouping.

To literally match the parenthesis, they need to be escaped. You were correct to attempt to escape them with a "\". However, you did not also escape the "\" in the double-quoted string.

Notice that when you add the backslash before the parenthesis, it does not actually change the double-quoted String. This is because the backslash is used as an escape sequence.

```
puts "foo bar\(2\) bletch"
#=> "foo bar(2) bletch"
```

You need to also escape the backslash in the String by using another backslash:

```
puts "foo bar\\(2\\) bletch"
#=> "foo bar\(2\) bletch"
```

This would pass the correct String to be used in the Regexp.

Alternatively, you could use a single-quoted String to remove one of the escape sequences:

```
puts 'foo bar\(2\) bletch'
#=> "foo bar\(2\) bletch"
```

To summarize, you need to escape the special characters by doing either:

```
# Using double-quoted string:
tester ( "foo bar\\(2\\) bletch" )

# Using single-quoted string:
tester ( 'foo bar\(2\) bletch' )
```

Comment: Thank you, Justin.  I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks again Justin, that's the information I needed.  Since I am processing data (from a database), I wrote a gsub to escape the string.